Are pilots flying parabolic flights less prone to sickness than their passengers?
Parabolic flights to simulate zero g are notorious for inducing motion sickness in their passengers. Are pilots equally likely to get sick during such flights? If they aren't, why not?

They are less likely than occasional passengers to become sick for several reasons:

They do it more frequently and therefore become conditioned to the feeling of weightlessness.
They can see the horizon and know what to expect, so the primary cause of motion sickness, (a mismatch in the body's sensory inputs) is mitigated.
People who are very sensitive to motion sickness generally don't seek professional pilot careers, especially in such a specialized field as this, so there is a natural screening process in place.

There may be other contributing factors as well, but these are the main ones.

I'd imagine that prior to becoming a vomit comet pilot, one takes a ride in the back of said vomit comet. If one vomits, one fails the interview process and goes on to a different piloting path.
